# Ninja-IDE for Django or Python

Tags: python, django, ide

I'm looking for a good IDE to programming with Python, I found this http://ninja-ide.org/.

Did anyone try Ninja-IDE to programming Python or Django Apps, any suggestions about its use?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! :) Please note that your question is explicitly listed in the [faq] as inappropriate for our community: _your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”_ For more information on what we like to see in our questions, please read  [Writing the Perfect Question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I prefer Aptana Studio 3, try it [here](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3)!

Answer (score 0):

I personally use Netbeans for Python development mostly because I also use it for PHP and Java development. It works quite well for Python.